# Change TabTip.exe input method

Tags: c#

I am developing an Windows Application using C# running on Windows 10. I used virtual keyboard TabTip.exe for input. Since the application needs to input both Chinese (Cangjie) and English, may I ask if there is any way to show TabTip.exe with specific input method instead of clicking the icon on virtual keyboard? Thanks

Comment: Isn't that a *user setting*? Controlled through the keyboards `Language Preferences` setting? In any case, Windows has many input methods. You can't try to control all of them. If you want a textbox to use a specific keyboard layout you'll have to specify it using an appopriate method. In UWP applications you can use [Input Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx) to specify that a field expects a phone, email, *Chinese text*, etc. The available input scopes [are here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue).

Comment: InputScope is also available for [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscope.aspx) applications with similar [Input Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: BTW what kind of application are you building? UWP? WPF? Windows Forms? Input technologies vary between them with Windows Forms offering the least choice since it's the oldest technology

Comment: My application need to show virtual keyboard on screen. The application is on Windows Form and now trying to use TabTip.exe for application. Since the application needs chinese input as well as english (handwriting also), I would see if there is any ways to control TabTip.exe to change the input method. Thanks

Comment: You do that by using the proper APIs for Input methods, (IMEs), not trying to control the *utilities* that implement them. IMEs are part of the Windows API itself, which means you can find a *lot* of documentation on how they work, how they can be controlled etc going back decades.

Comment: In this case, googling for `Windoes Forms IME` returns the [Contor.ImeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.imemode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ImeModeBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imemode(v=vs.110).aspx) related properties in the top results. As you'll see though the ImeMode supports far fewer options. What was only supposed to support Japanese and Chinese 10 years ago is now used to display numeric,email, multilingual keyboards on tablets and phones

Comment: If you *have* to use Windows Forms, and want more than what ImeMode provides, you could use WPF controls and forms in Windows Forms. WPF and especially UWP though was built with touch, tablets etc in mind. [This article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/) describes how you can use WPF in a Winforms application or a Winforms control in WPF